# javascript how to repeat the replace function to execute for every empty space in a sentence

Tags: javascript, replace, repeat

I am writing a program that needs to parse each word of a sentence which user is inputing in a text field and performs work of outputing each word of the sentence to a seperate line. I am very close, i was able to get it to do so with the replace function on every space to replace with a 
 but it is only doing it to the first space. How could I get it to repeat it with every space not know how many words the user will input in his sentence? So far this is what I have.

```
<header>
    <h1>Parse Test</h1>
</header>
<br>
<p>Please enter facts:</p>
<input id="inp" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="pass()">Process</button>
<br>
<p id="iop"></p>
<br>
<script>

    function pass() {

        var lx = document.getElementById("inp").value;
        var tx = lx.replace(" ","<br>");
        document.getElementById("iop").innerHTML = tx;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: use a regular expression as the first argument to replace, with appropriate porperties to make it match multiple

Comment: Use **/ /g** instead of **" "**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a regular expression, and tell it to apply globally with the `g` flag:

```
var tx = lx.replace(/ /g, '<br>');
```

**Simplified working example:**

```js
console.log('A few different words'.replace(/ /g, '<br>'));
```

Comment: AWESOME! I have not seen the g flag before. This worked perfect! I have been researching for days and this never came up or I didn't catch it. Thank you so much!

Comment: if there are multiple spaces between the words you end of having multiple `<br/>`. I would recommend using `text.replace(/\s+/mg, '<br />');` instead.